# Packaging external files with JavaFX deployment

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have a JavaFX app that reads in a configuration file.  I'd like the config file to remain outside of the jar to facilitate modification without recompiling.  Is there a way to set up netbeans to grab the config file and include it in the installer?

I've found the option to change to icon and that works fine but I haven't been able to discover how to tell it to also include specific external resources.

I've read the information posted here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm but I'm still not seeing a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to do this (though I may be wrong). I needed something similar to this once, and the approach I took was

1. Package the file in the jar file
2. At program start-up time, check to see if the file exists in the expected location on the local drive
3. If it's there, read it, etc
4. Otherwise, read the contents from the jar and write them to the expected file

This solves the problem of "deploying outside the jar", and it also solves the problem of the user inadvertently deleting the file after deployment, etc.

Comment: This was going to be my fallback plan but it's probably better to do it that way as you make a good case for it in your last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this issue (due to having many dependent .dll's and other type items) was to use netbeans to compile the jar, which has things like images/css/fxml etc. etc. and then use an Inno Script to actually compile and configure the installer, since inno makes it pretty straightforward to include extra resources. I have yet to find a way to do this properly within javafx itself.